# unable to use $off and passing parameters in eventbus in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-bus

In main.js i created the eventBus

```
Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue()
```

And in component1

```
this.$eventHub.$emit('logged-in')
```

In component2, i tried this

```
  beforeMount () {
     this.$eventHub.$on('logged-in', function () {
       console.log("logged in")
     })
   },
   beforeDestroy() {
     this.$eventHub.$off('logged-in')
   }
```

It is not printing any thing in the console. If i remove `this.$eventHub.$off('logged-in')` it is working fine, but it is executing number of times that`$emit` is executed. What am i doing wrong here? why `$off` is not working?

Unable to pass the **parameters** as well
trying to send message using `$emit`

```
this.$eventHub.$emit('logged-in', "some message")
```

in `$on`

```
this.$eventHub.$on('logged-in', this.testEvent)
```

The test event method looks

```
    testEvent (params) {
      console.log(params)
    }
```

The params shows undefined.

But if i do this, it is working fine

```
        this.$eventHub.$on('logged-in', (params) => {
          console.log(params)
        })
```

How can i pass parameters to the method?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a reference to `$off`

```
beforeMount () {
 this.$eventHub.$on('logged-in', this.onEventHandler)
},
beforeDestroy() {
 this.$eventHub.$off('logged-in', this.onEventHandler)
},
methods: {
  onEventHandler () {
    console.log("logged in")
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working but in both cases like `$off` `$on` it is printing 'logged in' right. Actually what i want is, to execute the onEventHandler method when it emits not when it destroy. How can i do that?

Comment: And is it possible to pass a message while`$emit` ?

Comment: `$on` means register event and `$off` means unregister event. If you want to pass parameter, just add to `onEventHandler (params)`

Comment: Unregistering the event is working fine, but not able to pass any params.
`this.$eventHub.$emit('logged-in', "sample message")` , then in the `$on` i did this `this.$eventHub.$on('logged-in', this.testEvent())` . The test event method looks `testEvent: function (params) {
      console.log(params)
    }`

Comment: As you said i added the params, still any thing wrong?

Comment: Updated my question, i added my problem briefly, please check once, Thanks.